# aligning text inside of a div center top

Tags: css, html, text, alignment

Im trying to align first a div to the center. Inside that div are 3 other divs with some text inside them and i want to align that text to the center top of the inner divs.

I wrote this jsbin webpage but the inner text isn´t center at the top and the out div isnt center

http://jsbin.com/beyuhaxe/1/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="all">
  <div id="uno" class="try">
    <p>try1</p>
  </div>

  <div id="dos" class="try">
    <p>try2</p>
  </div>

  <div id="tres"  class="try">
    <p>try3</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

css

```
#uno{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

#dos{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

#tres{
  background-color: red;
  width:100px;
  height:50px; 
}

#all{
  width:400px;
  margin: auto;
}

.try {
  position:relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right:10px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: So is it the text you want to align to the center (which it is) or the divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math (400-300) / 4 = 25px for equal spacing on your inner div.

```
.try {
  position:relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right:25px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

also, doing a css reset will help you make sure you don't have other margins or padding somewhere.

Comment: and how do i put the text to the top also?

Comment: Again, you need to reset your css.  if you set your paragraph top margin to zero, text will float to the top.  Your default margins are pushing it down.  If you google CSS reset, you will find a good default set of tags to reset.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles are inheriting a `margin`, to over-ride this you could put:

```
p { 
    margin:0;
}
```

but you should consider this in a reset at the top of your **css** file, then to center the outer div, i would use:

```
#all{
    width:400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```